# Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference - OnLoadMoreListener recyclerview

Tags: android

I'm new to `Android`. Trying to implement Infinity Scrolling using this tutorial http://www.devexchanges.info/2017/02/android-recyclerview-dynamically-load.html. But, data comes from my server.

when I try to load more data using `OnLoadMore` listener I get the error

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.odianewswithapi.Adapters.TopNewsAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(com.example.odianewswithapi.Interfaces.OnLoadMoreListener)' on a null object reference

Here is my complete code - https://github.com/jupitorapps/news_pupulputul_odia/tree/loadMoreFunction

at onCreate

```
    makeApiCall(); //to get data and putinto recycler view

    loadMoreData();
```

here is full code of the above function

```
public void makeApiCall(){
    ApiService service = ApiClient.getRetrofit().create(ApiService.class);

    Call<List<TopSavedNewsModel>> call = service.get_top_news();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<TopSavedNewsModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<TopSavedNewsModel>> call, Response<List<TopSavedNewsModel>> response) {
          //  Log.d("TAG","Response body:  "+response.body());

            generateTopNewsList(response.body());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<TopSavedNewsModel>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}

private void generateTopNewsList(List<TopSavedNewsModel> topNewsList){

    if (topNewsList.size() ==0 ){
        noSavednewsView = findViewById(R.id.noTopNews);
        noSavednewsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.topNewsRecyclerView);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        topNewsAdapter = new TopNewsAdapter(recyclerView,topNewsList,this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(topNewsAdapter);

    }
}


public void loadMoreData(){
    Log.d(LOGTAG,"Adapter item count: "+topNewsAdapter);

    topNewsAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLoadMore() {

            if (topNewsList.size() <= 20) {
                topNewsList.add(null);
                topNewsAdapter.notifyItemInserted(topNewsList.size() - 1);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        topNewsList.remove(topNewsList.size() - 1);
                        topNewsAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(topNewsList.size());

                        //Generating more data
                        int index = topNewsList.size();
                        int end = index + 10;
                        for (int i = index; i < end; i++) {
                            TopSavedNewsModel topSavedNewsModel = new TopSavedNewsModel();
                            //     contact.setPhone(phoneNumberGenerating());
                            //    contact.setEmail("DevExchanges" + i + "@gmail.com");
                            makeApiCall();
                            topNewsList.add(topSavedNewsModel);
                        }
                        topNewsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        topNewsAdapter.setLoaded();
                    }
                }, 2000);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(TopNewsActivity.this, "Loading data completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

When I comment `loadMoreData()` data loads and works fine except infinity scrolling.

I want to load next items by infinity scrolling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You get null pointer exception because you call `makeApiCall()` and `loadMoreData()` in `onCreate()`. So `makeApiCall()` start executing first and inside `makeApiCall()` method you call `API` (call.enqueue()  works in the background.) that's why before finishing `makeApiCall()` method your second method `loadMoreData()` start executing and inside this method you `setOnLoadMoreListener` to `topNewsAdapter` but your topNewsAdapter not initialize yet means `null`.

You have to initialize `topNewsAdapter`, `topNewsList` and `recylerView`  in `onCreate()` before you call `makeApiCall()` and `loadMoreData()` like following.

```
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.topNewsRecyclerView);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    topNewsList = new ArrayList() // declear topNewsList as ArrayList in Global scope like topNewsAdapter 
    topNewsAdapter = new TopNewsAdapter(recyclerView,topNewsList,this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(topNewsAdapter);

    makeApiCall(); //to get data and putinto recycler view
    loadMoreData();
```

And change your `generateTopNewsList` like following.

```
private void generateTopNewsList(ArrayList<TopSavedNewsModel> list ){

    if (list .size() ==0 ){
        noSavednewsView = findViewById(R.id.noTopNews);
        noSavednewsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {
        topNewsList.addAll(list);
        topNewsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Another way you can avoid this `null pointer exception` by calling `loadMoreData()` inside `generateTopNewsList()` like following.

```
    makeApiCall(); 
    loadMoreData(); // remove this line frome here
```

```
private void generateTopNewsList(List<TopSavedNewsModel> topNewsList){

    if (topNewsList.size() ==0 ){
        noSavednewsView = findViewById(R.id.noTopNews);
        noSavednewsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.topNewsRecyclerView);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        topNewsAdapter = new TopNewsAdapter(recyclerView,topNewsList,this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(topNewsAdapter);
        // add below line here
        loadMoreData();

    }
}
```